# React route is not working | React Router

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I install npm install react-router-dom@6 and set route path..

```
import React from "react";
import * as ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { BrowserRouter, Switch, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import "./App.css";
import HeaderBar from "./components/HeaderBar/HeaderBar";
import SignIn from "./components/SignIn/SignIn";
import SignUp from "./components/SignUp/SignUp";

function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <BrowserRouter>
        <HeaderBar />
        <Route path="/">
          <SignIn />
        </Route>
        <Route path="/signup">
          <SignUp />
        </Route>
      </BrowserRouter>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

The preview is not working. Didn't see any error. Why it is..? Please help me.

Comment: No error in the console? What does _not working_ mean?

Comment: Can you elaborate on what "not working" means?  Also, you might try moving `<HeaderBar />` out and see if that fixes the issue-- not sure if `<BrowserRouter/>` can have direct child components that aren't `<Route/>`s...

Comment: I see errors in the console when running this locally. A <Route> is only ever to be used as the child of <Routes> element, never rendered directly. Please wrap your <Route> in a <Routes>. Similarly, once fixing that there are more errors. I'd check the docs on how `BrowserRouter` works

Comment: @Tom That would be an error from using `react-router-dom` v6, but this code is importing and using `react-router-dom` v5 components and route syntax.

Comment: @DrewReese based on the original question I'm not sure that's true -- `I install npm install react-router-dom@6 and set route path`

Comment: @Tom I'm not sure what you mean by original question, it's not been edited. I meant that you installed a different version from what it appeared the OP was using as all the code in the example snippet is v5 code. If you ran `npm i -s react-router-dom@5` and ran the code you'd not see any of the errors you mention. It seems OP *did actually* install the RRD@latest though and was referencing old docs or tutorial, etc...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to use `Routes` rather than `Switch` for react-router-dom@6. Something like this:

```
<BrowserRouter>
    <Routes>
      <Route path="/" element={<App />}>
      </Route>
    </Routes>
  </BrowserRouter>
```

Comment: This is unbelievable, I spend a night just for knowing that they are change the attribute of "component" into "element", and thanks for this.

Comment: The basic example on the React routes page doesn't include the ```element``` attribute. Thank you! That solved it for me.

Answer (score 2):

The only thing I can see as "not working" is that both routes will match and be rendered with the path is `"/signup"`. The router components ***inclusively*** render all matching `Route` and `Redirect` components.

You likely want to wrap the routes in a `Switch` component so the routes are ***exclusively*** matched and rendered.

[Switch](https://v5.reactrouter.com/web/api/Switch)

> Renders the first child `<Route>` or `<Redirect>` that matches the
> location.

Keep in mind also that within the `Switch` component that path order and specificity matters. You will want to order the paths from *more* specific paths to *less* specific paths. `"/"` is about as general as it gets, so should be rendered *after* the more specific `"/signup"` path.

```
import { BrowserRouter, Switch, Route } from "react-router-dom";

function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <BrowserRouter>
        <HeaderBar />
        <Switch>
          <Route path="/signup">
            <SignUp />
          </Route>
          <Route path="/">
            <SignIn />
          </Route>
        </Switch>
      </BrowserRouter>
    </div>
  );
}
```

If the issue is that you've installed `react-router-dom` version 6 and you are working from an outdated tutorial, then replace the `Switch` component for the *required* `Routes` component and render the routed components on the `Route` component's `element` prop ***as JSX***.

```
import { BrowserRouter, Routes, Route } from "react-router-dom";

function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <BrowserRouter>
        <HeaderBar />
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/signup" element={<SignUp />} />
          <Route path="/" element={<SignIn />} />
        </Routes>
      </BrowserRouter>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't why you are not getting the error but I have added the working code you can try it

```
import React from "react";
import * as ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { BrowserRouter, Switch, Route, Routes } from "react-router-dom";
import "./App.css";
import HeaderBar from "./components/HeaderBar/HeaderBar";
import SignIn from "./components/SignIn/SignIn";
import SignUp from "./components/SignUp/SignUp";

function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <BrowserRouter>
        <HeaderBar />
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/" element={<SignIn />} />
          <Route path="/signup" element={<SignUp />}/>
        </Routes>
      </BrowserRouter>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

You can use Route inside the Routes and pass your component inside the element

Answer (score 2):

New version 6 of React router had some major changes. so if you want your code to work then do as below.
You have to wrap your all of your routes in routes tag like below.

```
<BrowserRouter>
     <Routes>
         <Route path='/signin' element={<SignIn />} />
         <Route path='/signup' element={<SignUp />}  />
     </Routes>
</BrowserRouter>
```

And one more thing their shouldn't be anything in Routes tag except Route tags.